# Quais são as opções para desenvolvimento de aplicativos mobile?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

Estou com uma ideia para desenvolver um aplicativo móvel, para rodar nas plataformas Android e IOS.

Eu nunca desenvolvi nada mobile, então não faço ideia de quais são as opções de tecnologia para desenvolver.

Gostaria de algumas sugestões.

Comment: pesquise melhor. há alguns tópicos assim por aqui e milhões de conteúdo na internet.

Comment: Com um pouco de pesquisa poderá entender melhor os conceitos de desenvolvimento mobile. Assim poderá ter uma melhor ideia do que deverá fazer. Além disso aconselho que teste o desempenho de apps Nativos em comparação a apps Híbridos, isso também pode de direcionar na melhor escolha.

Answer (score 6):

Primeiro se pergunte, o que eu sei! 
A partir dai vamos a algumas opcoes

**Native**
Desenvolver apps de forma nativa, tecnicamente é uma ótima pratica, porem com uma curva de aprendizagem demorada.

1. IOS - Utilizando Swift ou Objective-C
2. Android - Utilizando Java

**Hibrido (Webview)**
Forma de desenvolver apps utilizando HTML, CSS e Javascript. Baixa curva de aprendizagem, alem de se bem desenvolvido, o app chega a ficar legal.

Alguns Frameworks:

1. [IONIC](https://ionicframework.com/)
2. [FRAMEWORK7](https://framework7.io/)
3. FAMO.US

entre outros.

**Cross-Platform**
Basicamente seguindo o mesmo contexto do de cima, porem ao invés de ser uma WebView, gera apps nativos. Muitos utilizam JavaScript para esse fim. Outros geram código intermediário. Outros ainda usam um código intermediário C para compilar para nativo da plataforma.

Exemplos:

1. [ReactNative](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)
2. [NativeScript](https://www.nativescript.org/)
3. [Weex](https://weex.apache.org/guide/index.html)
4. [Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/)
5. [TotalCross](http://www.totalcross.com/)
6. [Code Name One](https://www.codenameone.com/)
7. [Gluon](http://gluonhq.com/)

Sabendo disso tudo, cabe a você decidir qual se enquadra melhor nesse momento.

Abraços

Comment: Legal, obrigado.

Comment: @PedroFilipe Caso tenha ajudado, marcar a resposta como resolvido. Abraços

Comment: Sugeri algumas outras ferramentas Cross que eu conheço, tanto da que eu desenvolvo quanto de concorrentes.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Aceitei, valeu!